# how to bring up keepassX window with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: linux, keepassx

Is there any way to bring up the `keepassX` window when the application is started but the window is hidden? I mean that the application is running but only the icon in the notification area is visible. Is there any way to do this? Is there any way to configure a shortcut?

Comment: Which Desktop Environment are you using? Gnome? Unity? KDE? Xfce? Cinnamon?

Comment: Sorryfor delay: Unity and Mate

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly an answer for KeepassX and kind of a workaround...

I tend to use [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) in those cases, it's great for window tinkering and automation.

You could do something like `xdotool search --name keepassX windowactivate` 
Just make sure `--name` is the same as the window title.

And then make a keyboard shortcut to that command or put it in Keepass's launcher.

Comment: Works for me: `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "DatabaseName - KeePassX" windowactivate` (if the database was named) or `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "FileName.extension - KeePassX" windowactivate`

Comment: What about toggle window (activate/minimize)? https://superuser.com/questions/1369564/keyboard-shortcut-for-toggle-window-activate-minimize

Comment: I think you have to write a script or use another tool for that. See my answer in your new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but it reaches the same goal (kind of).

In `settings` > `General` > `Auto-Type`

There is the global option `Global Auto-Type shortcut`

Doesn't bring keepassXC's windows to front (I also wish of a none-hackish way of doing it, check the last dot).

But it brings a search box with your entries, you can then:

- it only searches in entries with an Auto-Type entries
- search your entries depending on the current active windows (A checkbox all database is available)
- by pressing `Ctrl + {1,2,3}` it **auto-type** your `username`, `password` or `totp` respectively.
- enter triggers your auto-type for selected entries.
- Seems that: after a time (1 sec), pressing the `esc` key brings the main window to front.

Comment: This is a very plausible solution. At least the best we have at the moment. Thank you! Though it is odd that we cannot copy the password from this mini-window using CTRL-C

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and made an open-source solution based on xdotool for that.

https://hyperkeys.xureilab.com

After install, click on the "HK" icon in the tray, then add a macro. Choose "Window Pin by name". Click on the gear next to it and type 'KeePassX'. Then click on the pen to set your shortcut.

Personally, I'm using ALT+P to bring KeePassX on the foreground. The app must be already running, however. So I made it start on boot.

Answer (score 0):

bring keepass to foreground or start it up if not running

```
xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --pid $(ps aux|grep keepass|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'))||keepassxc
```